# How to send Accept Encoding header with curl in PHP

Tags: php, curl, gzip

How to send Accept Encoding header with with curl in PHP

```
  $data=json_encode($data);
$url = 'url to send';
$headers = array(
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);        
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 4);
    $datas  = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

How to Decompress the response

Comment: The `Content-Type` header is sent from the server to the client. You're looking for `Accept*` headers. (e.g. `Accept`, `Accept-Encoding`, `Acccept-Language`). This tells the server what your user agent supports.

Comment: @Mike not exactly,  the client can also send `Accept-Encoding` header requests.

Comment: @PedroLobito Interesting. How does that differ from `Accept`?

Comment: `14.3 Accept-Encoding` - https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

Comment: @PedroLobito Sorry, I misread your first comment here. I thought you were saying the client can send `Content-Type`. From the link above, `The Content-Type entity-header field indicates the media type of the entity-body sent to the recipient`, so I was right; it can only be sent from the server to the client.

Comment: @mike here's a request send from my browser to this page - http://pastebin.com/GaTXDnfM -  You can see clearly that me, the client, is requesting `Accept-Encoding:`

Comment: I misunderstood your first comment, we're both right... :)

Answer (score 8):

You can use `CURLOPT_ENCODING`:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
```

> The contents of the "Accept-Encoding: " header. This enables decoding
> of the response. Supported encodings are "identity", "deflate", and
> "gzip". If an empty string, "", is set, a header containing all
> supported encoding types is sent.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

---

Alternatively, you can send an header:

```
$headers = array(
        'Accept: text/plain'
    );
```

To force the response in `text/plain`

Comment: Accept: text/plain doesn't force anything.  Results still HTML.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean how to ungzip the response I did it like this:

```
<?php
....
$headers = array(
    "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate",
    "Accept-Charset: utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3",
    "Accept-Language:en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4",
    "Connection: keep-alive",
);
....
$response = curl_exec($curl);
// check for curl errors
if ( strlen($response) && (curl_errno($curl)==CURLE_OK) && (curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)==200) ) {
    // check for gzipped content
    if ( (ord($response[0])==0x1f) && (ord($response[1])==0x8b) ) {
        // skip header and ungzip the data
        $response = gzinflate(substr($response,10));
    }
}
// now $response has plain text (html / json / or something else)
```